# Stable sort with OrderBy

Tags: c#, linq

This question is similar to others asked  here, but none gives me the exact answer I am looking for.

I have a `List` as follows:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>> lstValuesTemp = new List<KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>>();
lstValuesTemp.Add(...);
```

Then, I want to do a stable sort of the list with `OrderBy` on the string key of the `KeyValuePair` with an anonymous function - something like this:

```
var sortedArray = lstValuesTemp.OrderBy(a =>
{
       //What to put here?             
});
```

2 problems:

1. What to put in the function?
2. I get a compiler error:

   > error CS0411: The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.OrderBy(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you *want* to sort by?  What aspects of the documentation of `OrderBy` did you find confusing?  What information on the subject have you found when researching how to use `OrderBy` in other common resources and what confused you in those resources?

Comment: Well, what do you want to order by? The keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can order by the key like this :

```
var ordered = lstValuesTemp.OrderBy(v => v.Key);
```

or you can order with fonction

declare the function like this:

```
public static string CustomOrder(KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> item)
{
    //TODO: add some logic that return a string to compare this item
}
```

and than call thia function:

```
var ordered = lstValuesTemp.OrderBy(CustomOrder);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to order by the key, then the lambda needs to pull the key out of your object. So since your List is of `KeyValuePair`s, it'd just be `a => a.Key`.

If you're confused by what it actually means to order by a string (or some other type), you should look into the `IComparable<T>` interface. This is implemented by a class of type `T` to provide a way to compare objects of type `T` to say that one element either precedes, follows, or has the same position as another. As described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35f0x18w.aspx), `String` implements `IComparable<String>`

Answer (score 1):

For the method, you can do it this way

```
var sortedArray = lstValuesTemp.OrderBy(a =>
{
    return a.Key;
});
```

Since you're only doing member access, you can also [shorthand your Lambda](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) to the following

```
.OrderBy(a => a.Key);
```

For the compiler error, the reason that error occurs is simply because you haven't filled out your method.

Since [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534966%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) expects a [Func](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it can't infer the TResult from usage since you haven't returned anything. If you did specify type arguments, it would complain about there not being a return value from your anonymous method.

EDIT: Assuming this isn't terribly abstracted, see also the [SortedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class